# KML to google maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-earth

I have a KMZ file containing an animation for google earth.
the KMZ contains KML with  and a series of PNGs to overlay in a latlng boundary.

I want to 'port' this to google map api, but some tags (timespan importantly) are unsupported.

What is the most painless way to start accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking a look at [geoxml](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml/). It supports a different KML subset to GGeoXml. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any documentation for it, so you'd have to just try it and see what happens. Although the project has an open source licence, the source code doesn't actually appear to be available, so you can't add the tags you need if they turn out not to be supported.